# Can you make a remote connection in Solaris 7 unix appear to be local?

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, hardware-interface

I am running a hardware test on stand that runs a GUI simulation in Solaris 7 SPARC machine.

I can not turn on power to the test equipment remotely because the simulation code checks to see if your local. I can not change the test stand code because I do not have access to it and even if I could do it I would have to spend 10's of thousands of dollars re-certifying it. Re-certifying is not an option. This is just a nuisance and would make me more productive.

So is there a way to trick the host in to thinking your local but your really remote?

I am using telnet and an x server from windows to access the box remotely.

I cannot use SSH.

Comment: Do you know (or can you find out) *how* the simulation code checks to see if you are local? That seems like the key bit of information here.

Comment: I have access to the code. The code is used across several projects. That is another reason I can not change it. Ironically the code used to have a switch to turn that "interlock" off. (Yes I know you should not break an interlocks but it is OK here as far as safety.)

Comment: I meant the DISPLAY variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like the equipment might be checking the source address of a connection to see whether you are considered "local". If you're connecting from `localhost`, then the connection is considered local.

The solution is to *make* a connection from localhost!

1. Telnet into the server box. This creates a connection from your Windows box to the server.
2. Telnet from the server back into itself (`telnet localhost`). This creates a new connection that looks like it's local.
3. Set up whatever `DISPLAY` environment variable you need to display X stuff on your Windows box.

Comment: Does not work. It uses the DISPLAY variable. So even if I got that to a local machine DISPLAY is still my windows box

Comment: So it will display locally if I set it to loaclhost:0.0 but that does not help me remotely.

Comment: It is like I need it to be at both places at once in that I can access the gui in both but the DISPLAY var needs to be localhost. Is that possible?

Comment: @Paul: I see. In that case, you can use something like [datapipe](http://jeff.bovine.net/Datapipe) to set up a simple tunnel between your server and your Windows box. Start a datapipe tunnel from say, port 6001 on the server to 6000 on your Windows box. Then set `DISPLAY=localhost:1` to point to port 6001 instead of the default 6000, so that the X connection will go through the local datapipe on the way to Windows. (If you could use ssh you could tunnel through that, but since you can't you'll have to use something else like datapipe.)

Comment: The X11 forwarding feature of ssh will set your DISPLAY to a local address like `localhost:10` and then redirect that to the remote X server on the machine you ssh from.

Comment: The box does not  have ssh. It is from 1989. I work on older test equipment. I am working on the 747-8 as a supplier for Boeing.

Comment: SSH would probably work. I am going to talk to IT about installing it.

Comment: From this website it basically says that SSH tunneling still sets the DISPLAY variable. http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-446725.html

Comment: Got SSH installed to code looks at local:0.0 xforwarding uses 10 and above.